# Need to generate SQL script file in every build of every changes in database project on TFS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Hi everyone,
            I want to accomplish a task in TFS that I need to auto generate the database changes as SQL script file in drop folder for every build.

For ex.: If I add a table in a database and then check in the changes, I need to get that create table script in the drop folder as .sql file extension

I want to automate the build too for every check in. Help me out and guide me a step by step procedure because since I am new to TFS build in visual studio.

Thanks

Comment: How are you versioning your database now?

Comment: Not versioning by any of the methods as of now. Just now we planned to maintain the database in TFS

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [ReadyRoll](http://www.ready-roll.com/)? This auto-generates a SQL migration script for each database change you choose to sync from your dev DB to your source controlled project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks David, I personally liked ReadyRoll very much after I seen their video demo but unfortunately our organisation atleast our project manager refused to proceed further with 3rd party tool. Is there any way to generate differential script on every build?

Comment: You might be able to do with with a bit of clever scripting as sqlpackage.exe can generate a script based on two dacpacs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should create a database project in visual studio and import your database schema. Once imported you can make any changes that you need to the project. The build output is a DACPAC that can be used to generate an update script on the fly for any target version upgrade.

http://www.benday.com/2012/12/18/deploy-a-sql-server-database-projects-dacpac-with-sqlpackage-exe/

If you want to use every traditional differing script model you should purchase ReadyRoll.

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh for your reply, As you said I did create project, import database and made some changes in the database.Until these steps I am clear but confused to proceed further, I mean DACPAC procedure. I am not aware of DACPAC build concept, Could you give me some links,in which DACPAC well explained and related to my scenario. My requirement is to get the differential script using arguments or by any other method without using any 3rd party tool. Thanks once again